# hyperlink to section of text in uitextview

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextview

I am trying to set up a 'Frequently Asked Questions' section on a UITextView. How do I link a line of text on a UITextView so that when the user clicks on it, the UITextView scrolls to a section of text in the same view. I would also like to underline the text and change the text color to blue.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Why do you want to do that with UITextView? UIWebView or WKWebView is the perfect fit for that.

Comment: I considered loading a .txt file into a uitextview that got loaded from a button click. I wasn't sure whether to use a uiwebview or uitextview

Answer (score 1):

try [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel)

`TTTAttributedLabel` allows you to automatically detect **links for dates, addresses, links, phone numbers, transit information, or allow you to embed your own**.

```
label.enabledTextCheckingTypes = NSTextCheckingTypeLink; // Automatically detect links when the label text is subsequently changed
label.delegate = self; // Delegate methods are called when the user taps on a link   (see `TTTAttributedLabelDelegate` protocol)

label.text = @"Fork me on GitHub! (http://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel/)"; // Repository URL will be automatically detected and linked

NSRange range = [label.text rangeOfString:@"me"];
[label addLinkToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://github.com/mattt/"] withRange:range]; // Embedding a custom link in a substring
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to first fetch the click event of the text  "Frequentry asked questions". on the click event you need to make code for scrolling.

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL inRange:(NSRange)characterRange
{

  //Set your character range here
  //   if match  return TRUE .
  //   else    return FALSE.

}
```

On successful character range fetch scroll your textView to the questions by using this method.

```
CGPoint bottomOffset;
bottomOffset = CGPointMake(0,(Y value of the question));
[self.chatOutput setContentOffset:bottomOffset animated:YES];
```

This method will scroll the uitextview to the position of your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableAttributedString * str = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Google"];
[str addAttribute: NSLinkAttributeName value: @"http://www.google.com" range: NSMakeRange(0, str.length)];
yourTextField.attributedText = str;
```

Comment: Code-only answers are auto-flagged as low quality and as such are discouraged on stackoverflow. In the future please embellish your answer with details and explain why it is a solution to the question. This helps other users.